# How do you represent a container that points to several objects?

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose we have the following:

```
struct main_container{
   struct sub_container* pointers;
}

struct object{
   char* name;
}

struct sub_container{
   //?
}
```

The idea is that `main_container`'s `pointers` is supposed to point to multiple `object`s, but I'm not sure what to put in `sub_container`. I was thinking something like `struct object** o;` but it seems like I have to allocate new memory for this, when all I'm trying to do is point to multiple objects that already exist in memory. So suppose 10 `object`s exist in memory, and `pointers` holds pointers to 4 random ones, or 6 random ones. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Store information about number of items and yes, allocate memory for array of pointers to objects (do not allocate memory for objects because they already exist).

Comment: Are you trying to create (dynamic) array or linked list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned you have to allocate the space for your pointer(s) dynamically if you like to add and remove more objects during runtime.

```
object** objects = malloc(NUM_POINTERS_TO_STORE * sizeof(struct object*));
```

and than you can access the n-th pointer by

```
struct object* nth_object = objects[n];
```

as long as n is less than NUM_POINTERS_TO_STORE.

When you want to modify your container very often during runtime you might want to write some accessing functions. I wrote a short example for a vector-like container.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct
{
    char* name_;
    // other data
} object;

typedef struct
{
    object** objects_;
    int size_;
    int alloc_;
} object_container;

object_container* oc_create()
{
    object_container* oc = malloc(sizeof(object_container));
    if(!oc) return NULL;
    oc->size_ = 0;
    oc->alloc_ = 1; // use an initial size 
    oc->objects_ = malloc(oc->alloc_ * sizeof(object*));
    return oc;
}

void oc_destroy(object_container* oc)
{
    if(oc) free(oc);
}

void oc_append(object_container* oc, object* o)
{
    assert(oc);
    assert(oc->objects_);
    assert(oc->alloc_ > 0);

    // reallocate memory if not enough space
    if(oc->alloc_ <= oc->size_) {
        oc->alloc_ *= 2;
        oc->objects_ = realloc(oc->objects_, (oc->alloc_ * sizeof(object*)));
        // some error checking would be good here
    }
    // append object
    oc->objects_[oc->size_++] = o;
 }

 object* oc_getat(object_container* oc, int index)
 {
     if(oc && oc->size_ > index) {
          return oc->objects_[index];
     }
     return NULL;
 }

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
     object_container* oc = oc_create();

     object o0, o1, o2;
     oc_append(oc, &o1);
     oc_append(oc, &o2);
     oc_append(oc, &o0);

     object* o = oc_getat(oc, 0);
     assert(o == &o1);
     o = oc_getat(oc, 5);
     assert(o == NULL);

     oc_destroy(oc);

     return 0;
 }
```

It is not yet complete and you might want to add more functionality but I think it should be enough to get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Need pointer to object? Then simply add it:

```
struct sub_container{
    struct object * ptr;
}
```

And the you could assign to it as:

```
struct main_container mc;
mc.pointers = malloc(20 * sizeof(*mc.pointers)); // Remember to check in real code if malloc fails
struct object obj;
mc.pointers[0].ptr = &obj; // Assign external object to container
```

But do you need `sub_container`? If all it does is hold one pointer, you could do get rid of it:

```
struct main_container{
    struct object** pointers;
}
```

and:

```
...
mc.pointers[0] = &obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to know the maximum number of objects ..
otherwise you have to allocate space for you pointers..

```
#define MAX_OBJS (10)

struct sub_container
{
    struct object *obj[MAX_OBJS];
}
```

but I think there is no need for the sub_container?!